# Monacaでnend広告のリフレッシュ方法について

Tags: monaca, nend

お世話になります。
現在Monacaにてハイブリッドアプリの開発をしている者です。
表題にありますとおり、nend広告を導入しまして無事に表示させることが出来た
ところまでは良かったのですが
表示させた広告がページのリロードを行わない限り、何度表示させても広告が一向に変化しません。
出来れば、表示させる度に変化させたいのですがどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

現在は、以下のようにons-modalを使用し広告用のページとし
必要なタイミングでmodalをshowさせています。
このshowさせたタイミングで広告のリフレッシュを行うまたは
hideさせたタイミングでリフレッシュを行えればと思っております。

```
<ons-modal var="ad_modal" id="AdModal">
<div id="nend_wrapper">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js1.nend.net/js/nendAdLoader.js"></script>
</div>
<div id ="CloseBottonDiv">
    <label class="CloseBotton" onClick="AdModalHide()">Close</label>
</div>
</ons-modal>
```

一度、DOMから削除し、タグを動的にJS側で作成して突っ込んでみましたが
再表示は出来ませんでした；；；

どなたかご存知の方が居ましたらよろしくお願いいたします。。。

Answer (score 1):

angularjsで表示後にscriptタグを挿入しても動きませんので、angular-loadscript.jsというものをつかって、新しいnend scriptを挿入することで解決しています。

Comment: ご連絡が遅くなり誠に申し訳ございません。　tokubassさんご回答いただきまして誠にありがとうございます。　angularにそのようなものがあるとは知りませんでした；；目から鱗です！是非試してみたいと思います！

Answer (score 0):

nend側の問題なので、なかなか難しいですが、nendのスクリプトをざっとみたところ、`nendCommon.init()`でリフレッシュされるようです。ダイアログを開く時にリフレッシュするのであれば、

```
nendCommon.init();
modal.show();
```

でどうでしょうか？
(`nendCommon`は、https://js1.nend.net/js/nendAdLoader.js 内で定義されています)
　ただ、公開している呼び出し方ではないようなので、将来もこのやり方が使えるかどうかは分かりません。

[追記]
`nendCommon.init()`はリフレッシュではなくて、初期化処理でした。
そしてコメントでoTakさんが述べているように、これだけだと不要なscriptタグが増えてしまうため、それを削除する実装も必要のようです。

Comment: リフレッシュごとに`feed.php`の`script`タグが`body`タグ内に追加されるので注意が必要ですね。

Comment: なるほど、それは気づきませんでした。では、不要なscriptタグを削除する実装もしないといけないですね。本文に[追記]しました。

Comment: ご連絡が遅くなり誠に申し訳ございません。　他の業務が激務になりまったく手をつけられておりませんでした。。　KNaitoさん、oTakさん回答頂きまして誠にありがとうございます！！　そのような関数があったとは知りませんでした；；；もっとnend側のスクリプト等の動きも調べたり見ないとダメですね><　現在の業務が落ち着きましたら試してみたいと思います！